# PHP не дает читать папку, пока другой скрипт работает с ней

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Эх, давненько я сюда не заходил. :D

Всем доброго времени суток!

У меня такая ситуация:

**Есть первый скрипт**, который запускает пользователь. Этот скрипт выполняет какое-то задание, на протяжении долгого времени (1-10 минут), работая при этом с папкой, изменяя, добавляя оттуда файлы.

**Есть второй скрипт**, который запускается каждую секунду, и его задача читать названия этих файлов и проверять их наличие. Этот скрипт выполняется гораздо короче, чем 1 секунда (в среднем 0.008 секунд).

**НО! Все это работает на локальном сервере!** А как только я загружаю это на хостинг, то скрипт, который подсчитывает файлы (второй скрипт), выполняться не хочет, и браузер висит вместе с ним. Но как только первый скрипт заканчивает работу, то и второй тут же выдает результат. Но уже слишком поздно.

Вопрос: в чем дело? Куда копать?  
Уже перепробовал разные алгоритмы подсчета файлов, ни один не работает, все так же висит. Помогите...

Если ситуация безвыходная, то тогда еще такой вопрос:    
Как тогда научить  PHP  кидать пользователю запрос или информацию прямо во время его выполнения? И как тогда научить JavaScript принимать эти запросы и на них реагировать?
То есть в jQ есть функция `$.ajax()`, а как реализовать это в php? Знаю, есть nodeJS, но не уверен, что оно тут подойдет, да и заморачиваться с ним не хочу.

Всем спаcибо, надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: возможно, у хостера есть ограничение на кол-во потоков апача в один тред. И поэтому, исполнять больше одного никак не может.

Если есть доступ к консоли, запустите первый скрипт в консоли, а второй, короткий, как обычно браузером. Если проблема уйдет, то значит предположение выше верно.

Comment: @KoVadim я так понял писать хостеру?

Comment: очень интересное наблюдение! я бы это проверил в первую очередь.

Comment: Меня смущает 2 момента:

-первый скрипт выполняется больше минуты. Сталкивался с ситуацией когда виртуальный хостинг имел ограничение на время выполнения скрипта - 3 сек. Возможно вы выходите за его рамки. Как я понял, с файлами у вас работает php. Для работы с файлами он достаточно медленный. По-моему если сменить php на что-нибудь вроде c++, вы многократно выиграете в производительности.

-в HTTP все соединения инициирует клиент посылая запрос, а сервер на них отвечает. Т.е через Ajax вы можете отправить запрос на сервер, который его обработает и отправит ответ

Comment: @romeo спасибо огромное, помогли!

Comment: @igolka97 Оформил, как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При таком сценарии существует распространенная ошибка: [блог Александра "Sam Dark" Макарова](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/blokirovanie-sessiy-v-php) и [хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/37206/). Возможно причина как раз-таки в незакрытой сессии.